# How to use subquery in jena for pagination?

Tags: pagination, sparql, jena

I want to use jena for pagination. I use this query :

```
select distinct (?outEdge) (?inEdge) (?dest) (?source) { select distinct (?p as ?outEdge) (?q as ?inEdge) (?px as ?dest) (?qx as ?source)  {  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Japan> ?p ?px . } union { ?qx ?q <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Japan> . }  } order by ?p } offset 0 limit 10000
```

However this query works on online dbpedia endpoint (Viruoso) but in jena this error occurs :

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " ")" ") "" at line 1, column 585.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT (?x) ...` isn't legal SPARQL 1.1.  Try without the `()`

The form is `(expression AS variable)`

Jena accepts it as an extension using `SyntaxARQ`.

The syntax error would be at line 1 col 26.  "column 585" makes no sense. See http://www.sparql.org/query-validator.html